# Oracle 12c Identity column with Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: .net, oracle, fluent-nhibernate, identity

Recently my application database was updated to use Oracle 12c so in the creation of new tables I have used the new identity feature:

```
ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
```

Within my Fluent mapping I have configured:

```
Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
```

However when trying to save a new record I'm getting the following error:

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert:
>   [Entity][SQL: INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, AFFECTED_ID, AFFECTED_TYPE,
>   ACTION_TYPE, ACTION_OWNER, ENTITY_ID, ACTION_TIMESTAMP) VALUES
>   (hibernate_sequence.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) returning ID into
>   :nhIdOutParam] ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException:
>   ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

I can clearly see that its trying to use a sequence that doesn't exist.

Looking at the current version of Nhibernate the application is using seems to be out of date:

```
<package id="NHibernate" version="3.3.2.4000" targetFramework="net45" />
Fluent NHibernate 1.3.0.733
```

Does Fluent Nhibernate support Oracle 12c Identity feature if so how do I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to use

```
Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.SequenceIdentity("Your_Sequence_Name")
```

Regards

Comment: My understanding for using the IDENTITY  type in Oracle is that you don't have to write a supporting sequence, making the whole thing more streamlined. Therefore using SequenceIdentity("Your_Sequence_Name"), I can't see how that would work as I haven't defined a custom sequence.

Comment: Even when you are using the IDENTITY type in Oracle, it still creates a Sequence behind the scenes. You will have to use that sequence name. The "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY" is a shortened way of telling Oracle it is an auto increment field so that you don't have to go and specify the syntax for creating a sequence. I prefer to create the sequence myself since I can give it a name that complies with my naming convention on the database. Also to remember is that a system generated sequence - as are created by oracle through the "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY" syntax, cannot be dropped.